# Rails 3: POST request's parameters not converted to HashWithIndifferentAccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jmeter

I'm running some load testing on my app using JMeter (2.3.4x3.8). I'm having an issue where the parameters that are posted are not converted into an ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess (compared to when the POST request is posted from the browser). I looked into my Rails console and params is just a string. I've set the Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type etc but it still didn't solve my problem. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: What specific version of Rails?

Comment: It may not help with your problem, but please consider updating Rails to 3.2.6. 3.2.2 has known sql injection vulnerabilities.